# How to remove tab close buttons in VS2013?

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-2013

It looks like you can remove the tab close buttons in Visual Studio 2013 as part of the [Productivity Power Tools 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) extension, but that does a ton more stuff and seems like bigtime overkill just to get rid of those pesky per-tab close buttons.  Does anyone know of a nice simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. That option sets the following values in registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\DialogPage\Microsoft.CustomDocWell.Options]
    "HideButtonInTabs"="False"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\DialogPage\Microsoft.PowerCommands.OptionPages.CommandsPage]
    "DisabledCommands"=""
```

but they are not used by Visual Studio, only by the extension.
So the only way is to write your own VS extension that only does this one thing.

Comment: This answer seems to be about right; strangely, the Productivity Power Tools extension actually sets `HideButtonInTabs` to `False` when the close buttons are hidden; it should really be called `ShowCloseButtonInTabs` or something.